# Jquery dialog postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have one dialog like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=updateBI.clientID%>').click(function confirm () {
                $('div#thedialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); $("[id*=ButtonUPBI]").click(); },
                        "No, save draft": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); $("[id*=ButtonINBI]").click();},
                        "No": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); alert('Change has not been updated!')}
                    }
                });
                $('div#thedialog').dialog('open');
                return false;                    
            });
        })
```

I have asp buttons in visual studio.
After I click the button updateBI, the JQuery box shows up and stays there because of "return false". Now the problem is that suppose I click one button inside teh jquery dialog, the website doesn't postback, and I have to refresh by myself. I wonder how to handle that?
Thanks for advice!

Comment: You should probably add this line before calling dialog: `var currBtnId = $(this);` and then in your dialog buttons call `$(currBtnId).click()` - Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: This comment from Pavlo has made is a good way to accomplish this.  If @Pavlo posts it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: Not sure if it answers the OP's question, maybe my answer is not what the OP is expecting

Comment: thanks for your guys great help! it's just I'm a bit slow, and still trying to test..

Comment: I forgot the exact code after $(button).click(); I  deleted return false, and added e.preventDefault();, but problem still occur, I guess i need to do sth after $(button).click() to make it postback

Comment: sorry what does var currBtnId = $(this); mean?

Comment: `$(this)` means `$('#<%=updateBI.clientID%>')`

Comment: is it like  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=updateBI.clientID%>').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var currBtnId = $(this);

                $('div#thedialog').dialog({
                    
                    autoOpen: false,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); $("[id*=ButtonUPBI]").click(); $(currBtnId).click() } ?

Comment: Oh, I think you were talking about that your button which is `ButtonUPBI` is not fired? If yes, then try this on `$("input[id*=ButtonINBI]").click()` Or you have to tell me what is exact Id for button ButtonINBI, or just add some class for this button like `class="myBtnClass"` and then call `$(".myBtnClass").click()`

Comment: my buttonUPBI seems work fine, it has vb calls sql procedure that updates table, Problem is that say when I open website at 3:47, and click update at 3:49, sql database shows 3:49, but asp text box still shows 3:47. if i refresh website, it shows 3:49

Comment: I think this could take a long time for chatting here, because I think you should use ajax here, but you are not using it. So, the quick solution for you would be just refreshing the page like `location.reload();` - inside you dialog button

Comment: sorry, i'm new to jquery and ajax. location.reload()seem to not work well. Is there a better way than that? Would the ajax structure be similar to the code posted above?

Comment: i do have <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">, does that mean I'm using ajax?